# Notifications like facebook

Tags: 7

I searched for a module provide notification like one exist in facebook website.
I found [user notification](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=drupal%207%20user%20notifications&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://drupal.org/project/user_notifications&ei=unv5UMqHJ-KC4gTu_YGIBg&usg=AFQjCNG7AoGCnmwzc3gxm3f-AujGzrmZ9w&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bGE) but it's for D6.
is There a module can i use for what i need?  thanks.

Comment: have you checked http://drupal.org/project/heartbeat module

Comment: or the http://drupal.org/project/message

Comment: thank you for your help i will try the modules and replay later.